# Regex is not accepted but seems to be vaild

Tags: java, regex

I currently and trying to have a regex validate if a string has a 0 followed by either a 7 or 8. On regex101 it shows as valid but then java fails the match.
The regex I used is: `^(0[7-8])`

What seems to be valid: https://regex101.com/r/cQMh2k/2

But the java code shows to be false:

```
System.out.println("08863".matches("^(0[7-8])"));
// prints false
```

I have also tried these variations to no avail:

```
^(0{1}[7-8])
^(0*[7-8])
^([0][7-8])
```

Comment: `matches()` requires a full string match, use `Matcher#find`

Comment: You don't need the `-`, that is only to create a range. `[78]` is the same.

Comment: That `^` is redundant when using `matches()`.

Comment: Can't you use String.startsWith instead of regex?